# Using cherrypy for HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: python, http, blackberry, https, cherrypy

I set up an http(s) upload server using cherrypy for [uploading](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/progguide/files/uploading.html) something with a blackberry application. I use [this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HTTP_Post_multipart_file_upload_in_Java_ME) code to send data to the server but I always get a bad request (400) error. It gives no other debug info or anything to help. Any ideas abut what may be wrong or what can I do to learn more about the problem ?

This error line is like this:

`{My IP} - - [16/Nov/2012:11:35:32] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 400 1225 "" ""`

Comment: Make sure the route has POST enabled for it, I know in Bottle I had to set this manually as GET is set by defaults for routes. Also make sure you are actually POSTing the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server only returns 400-something messages, without any additional information, you can either set the 'engine.autoreload_on' config option to True, which should give you the detailed error messages + tracebacks when something goes wrong. Another option would be to specify filenames for log.access_file and log.error_file to redirect their output to specific files.